# Vorbis decoder for Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, oggvorbis, vorbis

Anyone know of a vorbis decoder library that can be used on Windows Phone 7?

The lack of native code interop make re-using any of the native code implementations difficult (impossible?) but if there are tricks to do that, I'm open to that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a managed implementation for mono called [csvorbis](https://github.com/mono/csvorbis/blob/master/README), it includes a sample which outputs a wav file this didn't need many changes to work with XNA's [SoundEffect](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Exploring-Silverlight-XNA-integration-on-Windows-Phone-7.aspx) class. I did a whole track at once, this took a few seconds in the emulator so you may need to stream it using DynamicSoundEffect for better results. The [mooncodecs](https://github.com/mono/mooncodecs) folder has a codec for the desktop version based on csvorbis which may be worth a look aswell.

Answer (score -1):

Ogg Vorbis is not a [supported codec on Windows Phone 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) and the platform supports no way of adding support for custom codecs.

The options available are to write your own decoder/converter in managed code or to convert the original source files.
I suspect the second option will be easier.

Comment: Thanks, but I know that already, which I why I asked this question. I wanted to check if someone has already attempted to write a vorbis decoder library for managed code - always better to check before you dive in to port something yourself.

Comment: @MarcusJ please note you're commenting on a question that is over 4 years old and specifically relates to Windows Phone *7*. My answer was specific to WP7. Yes, this is not the case in WP8 but that's not what my answer relates to.