# How can I decrease download and upload time of WAV files?

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone

I'm working on an App on the windows phone which is very sound, heavy, and these sounds need to play at the same time.  This means I need to use PCM WAV files to create SoundEffect classes.

The download time of these files are taking too long, and trying to use GZIP didn't compress the much.

What other ways are there to speed up the downloading time of these files.  I have tried finding an MP3 to WAV conversion class for the Windows Phone, but did not have much luck (everything seemed to only run server side)

I am open to any solution possible, as long as I can use the SoundEffect class (or similar) on the Windows Phone device with the files I have downloaded.   I really don't care how it gets compressed, or decompressed as long as it can do it on both the phone and server side, and it I can use the file in the SoundEffect class at the end of the process.

Thank you.

While I would love to write my own decoder, I'm not really being given the space or time to do that. (Nor would I even know where to start)

Comment: Have you looked into `MediaPlayer`? It supports multiple audio formats. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer

Comment: @Polynomial Yes, I have. However, I need multiple files to be playing on top of eachother (Simultaneously), and MediaPlayer and MediaElement do not allow that.

Comment: Interesting. Have you considered reducing the quality of the WAV file? You can halve the file size by using 22050Hz instead of 44100Hz sampling, and the quality difference on a phone's speaker will be negligible.

Comment: @Polynomial Yep, a 1 second file is still over 100K :(

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just store the file in the app package, or release updated sfx as part of update packages?

Comment: @Polynomial Yes, they are created dynamically on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the issue. What I did was I used [Ogg vorbis](https://github.com/mono/csvorbis) and the [OggSound class](http://oggsharp.codeplex.com/releases/view/85231), which converts the ogg into a dynamic sound effect.  It wasn't perfect but with some tinkering and wrappers I was able to get it all working.

Comment: thats cool.. i went other way of using wma with background audio

Comment: have you any links on how you were able to do this?

Comment: I used the information from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820361/vorbis-decoder-for-windows-phone-7

Answer (score 2):

There is a pure C# MP3 decoder at this URL: http://robburke.net/mle/mp3sharp/

You can use it to decode mp3's manually into Wave PCM audio and then create a new SoundEffect instance with the raw audio data.

This is based on a conversation i had on AppHub last year

Comment: Thanks, have you gotten that to work? I downloaded that a while ago, and had some compile errors, once I got the compiles errors fixed, I realized I had no idea how to actually do the conversion, or get data such as duration or anything else out of it.  Aslo, can it be used to convert WAV to mp3 for uploading?

Comment: this was the solution used by someone who was trying to find a way around it and used this as a solution. From what i read, it acts like a stream so you try IsolatedStorageFile.OpenFile() to create dest file and get output stream and then use CopyTo on Mp3Stream created (Much like expanding zip file)

Comment: Ok thanks, Looking into that now.  Do you have a link to the AppHub conversation?

Comment: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/94011/564038.aspx you can drop a message and if the chap replies you will get email notification

Comment: thanks for the links, however it's not helping making the situation any more clear.  I hope that for other users, Someone can update this answer with HOW to use the relevant API

Comment: I might do some work on sound files in coming days and will use this mechanism if you can wait a couple of days

Comment: This ended up not working for me, and instead I used an Ogg converter